# okta trying to retrieve token in postman

Tags: azure, postman, okta

Using this [article](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/27/five-minutes-serverless-functions-azure#how-a-client-would-consume-your-secured-serverless-api)

Trying to retrieve Okta token using postman but getting

```
"Invalid value for 'client_id' parameter."
```

I know the client_id is correct because it successfully works when I manually test my Azure function in Azure.

Plus, I can manually generate a token in Okta and then put that in the function call with `client_id` and `client_secret` in Postman and that works fine.

I'm using a Post http method.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess. Are you sure you are sending as `x-www-form-urlencoded` from the Azure Function? Have you tried posting it as `form-data`? Also, is client credential flow enabled for this client?

Comment: I'm using this article: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/27/five-minutes-serverless-functions-azure#how-a-client-would-consume-your-secured-serverless-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

The error ***"Invalid value for 'client_id' parameter"*** usually occurs if you are passing invalid **`Client_ID`** value.

Make sure you are passing the values from the Okta Portal like below:

[image]

When I passed the correct values, **I am able to generate the access token successfully** using the below Parameters:

```json
https://XXXX.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token

 

client_id:ClientId
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:scope
```

[image]

I created an Azure HTTP Trigger1, and selected the **HTTP methods** like below:

[image]

**I am able to call the Azure Function Trigger successfully like below:**

```json
https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1

 

token:token
client_id:ClientID
client_secret:****
```

[image]

Comment: Got it working, thanks to you...in the article, it shows that the authorization tab is using Basic Auth, however, I notice you weren't.